# Unable to launch Eclipse 4.1.2 after installing the Eclipse e4 tooling

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

After installing `Eclipse e4 Tools` in my Eclipse 4.1.2 from [update site](http://download.eclipse.org/e4/downloads/drops/S-0.12M6-201203151300/repository/).  I am getting error when launching the eclipse.exe "`An error has occurred. See the log file <my_workspace_path>\.metadata\.log"`. And the content of `.log` file are:

```
!SESSION 2012-04-06 16:00:01.609 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120223-0900
java.fullversion=J2RE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows XP x86-32 jvmwi3260sr5-20090519_35743 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20090519_035743_lHdSMr
JIT  - r9_20090518_2017
GC   - 20090417_AA
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -clean -console

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-04-06 16:00:17.343
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Array index out of range: 1
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI.segment(URI.java:1731)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.getBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.processHierarchy(E4Workbench.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.init(E4Workbench.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.<init>(E4Workbench.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$3.run(Workbench.java:534)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
```

I also tried the `eclipse.exe -clean` to launch it but getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably using the wrong update site had caused this issue. But to resolve this issue I manually deleted all the `plug-ins` named `org.eclipse.e4.tools*.*.jar` from the `plugins` directory of eclipse. Then I launched the eclipse with `-clean` option and it was launched without the error that I was getting earlier.

Comment: I tried this solution but it did not work for me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should not install 0.12 version in 4.1.2 please use 4.2 builds

Comment: Thanks for the reply @tomsontom. So I think using wrong update site was the cause of this issue.